# MySQL Update MAX id within a group

Tags: mysql

I have data in a table (called `SubTask`) that looks like this:

```
STID     ID       HIVAL   TASK
1        4                ...
2        4
3        4  
4        4        1
5        5
6        5
7        5
8        5 
9        5        1
```

As you can see, the `hival` column is marked with a 1 for the highest `stid` in each group (`stid` is a unique number). I haven't been able to figure out how to UPDATE the table to reflect this. Using the following query I am able to SELECT the records:

```
select stid, id, task from subtask where stid in (select max(stid) from subtask group by id)
```

Once selected, how do I UPDATE the records to put a 1 in the `hival` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE SubTask AS s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubTask AS s2
  ON s1.ID = s2.ID AND s1.STID < s2.STID
SET s1.hival = CASE WHEN s2.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END;
```

Comment: @Strawberry perhaps you'd like to post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

That `hival` column is completely redundant and having it is counter productive. As you have already found out, updating it is a complicated query and is a big performance hit. Worse still, you would have to update it every time the data changes.

Instead just drop that column and do

```
SELECT max(stid), id from subtask GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Yes, you should generally never store data that you can easily access or generate from existing data using SQL queries.

Comment: This query is part of a much larger (and more complicated query) which works perfectly -- IF the `hival` column is marked with a 1. I really didn't think this would be so hard, but... here I am.

Comment: You asked a question. I have answered that. How are we to know about the part you didn't disclose?

Comment: Even if it was a much larger query, that hival would still be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I question the benefit of the `hival` column, and wonder why that is actually needed, .. but that's not the question you asked.

---

If it's necessary to have the `hival` column, and populate it using the rules as described, I'd write a SELECT statement first, and then convert that to a multi-table UPDATE statement.

You've got the start of the query written already.

```
 SELECT q.id
      , MAX(q.stid)
   FROM subtask q
  GROUP BY q.id
```

Use that as an inline view. We can do an outer join to that. If we have a matching row, then hival should be 1, otherwise hival will be NULL.

Something like this:

```
  SELECT IF(s.id IS NOT NULL,1,NULL) AS new_hival
       , t.*
    FROM subtask t
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT q.id
                , MAX(q.stid) AS max_stid 
             FROM subtask q
            GROUP BY q.id
         ) s
      ON s.id       = t.id
     AND s.max_stid = t.stid
```

We can convert that into an UPDATE statement by replacing `SELECT ... FROM` with the `UPDATE` keyword, and adding a `SET` clause. (We probably want to set `hival` on other rows to a value other than 1. Here, we're assuming that it will be set to NULL.)

Something like this:

```
  UPDATE subtask t
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT q.id
                , MAX(q.stid) AS max_stid 
             FROM subtask q
            GROUP BY q.id
         ) s
      ON s.id       = t.id
     AND s.max_stid = t.stid
     SET t.hival = IF(s.id IS NOT NULL,1,NULL)
```

Again, write a SELECT statement first, which returns the new 'hival' value to be assigned, and verify that is working. After that is tested, then convert it into an UPDATE statement.

---

An entirely different question (one that wasn't asked) is evaluating whether the `hival` column is actually needed. That question is not addressed here.)

Comment: I wish I could award both of you the answer because they both worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I wouldn't have HIVAL there at all, but I think this would be the easiest way:

```
update SubTask as st_1 
left join SubTask as st_2 
  on st_1.ID = st_2.ID 
  and st_1.STID < st_2.STID
set st_1.HIVAL = 1 
where st_2.ID is null;
```

Comment: Similar to my answer, but in your case you wouldn't change the row that previously had the hival. So you could end up with two or more hivals per group.